# Which dependencies representation has been used in Syntaxnet / Parsey McParseface?

Tags: tensorflow, syntaxnet

[Parsey McParseface label map](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/models/parsey_mcparseface/label-map) has 46 labels, some labels **like mwe** can not be find in either [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/all.html) or [Stanford typed dependencies](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) Docs.

According to [comments in code here:](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/51238b1b5219a37ba145915efa764cca870e0d9f/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/text_formats.cc#L58)

> This CoNLL reader is compatible with the CoNLL-U format described at http://universaldependencies.org/format.html

I'm a little confusing here, which format has been used in Syntaxnet / Parsey McParseface?

Answer (score 2):

The map seems to match the Stanford Typed Dependencies list, as described [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf), mwe=multi-word expression.